# onpaste / paste event not firing for table on first few attempts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, onpaste

***Google Chrome specific -*** *this is an internal-use app that does not require cross-browser compatibility*

See http://jsfiddle.net/spetnik/vpcyt4yv/

I have a table into which I am attempting to allow pasting of data. I made the individual cells selectable as such:

```
<td tabindex="0">
```

I originally tried adding the onpaste event to the TD elements themselves, but this did not work at all. So instead, I added the event to the table element and just check to make sure that the focused element is a TD and then paste the data to that element:

```
document.getElementById("tblData").onpaste = function(evt){
    if(document.querySelector(":focus").tagName.toLowerCase() != "td"){
        return;
    }

    document.querySelector(":focus").innerText = evt.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
};
```

While this does essentially work, the event usually does not fire on the first attempt. It seems that I need to either a) click around in the table a random number of times (each time is different) or b) change focus to another window and then back again before the event fires. In the jsFiddle I have added a console.log() call to the very beginning of the event so that I can see exactly when the event fires in the debug pane.

See the above jsFiddle or just the result at https://jsfiddle.net/spetnik/vpcyt4yv/embedded/result/

Comment: Even after 7 years this problem & fix still applies. Removing `user-select: none` allows capturning the `onpaste` event. It's a necessary fix for latest Edge and Chrome (Chromium)

Comment: @KerwinSneijders now Firefox has the same issue 

Comment: I did not have this issue with the latest version of FireFox using the now normal `user-select: none`

Comment: It's weird. See https://jsfiddle.net/spetnik/p4tqmh98/ - in Firefox, the no-select div only receives the paste event if it receives the focus via tabbing. Otherwise once the "select" div has focus, even if you click on the no-select div or anywhere else on the page (except the input) the "select" div still receives the paste event. In Chrome, obviously the "no-select" div will never receive the event, but the "select" event will only receive it if it receives focus via clicking, but not if it receives it via tabbing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow. The culprit seems to be the -webkit-user-select/user-select CSS! I discovered this when I noticed that pasting would be allowed only after initially clicking and dragging the mouse over a cell (which explains the random clicking - only after I clicked until my mouse moved mid-click did it work). I removed this CSS and now it works. Of course, now I need to find a workaround to prevent selecting, but at least I'm no longer stumped.

**Edit:** It seems that on a normal element (e.g. a DIV with the onpaste set to the element itself) onpaste does not work at all when -webkit-user-select is set to none. I submitted a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506859&thanks=506859&ts=1435930501)

**EDIT 2:** I have managed to find the following workaround: If I programmatically select the contents of the cell before Ctrl-V is pressed, then it will work, even with -webkit-user-select set to none. I accomplished this by adding the following event handler (jQuery shown here) to the TD (this still does not work in a standalone DIV with -webkit-user-select set to none):

```
$(elem).click(function(evt){
    var selection = window.getSelection();            
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(this);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
})
```